# cannot complete docker build of a c program

Tags: docker, gcc

I am using the gcc image from hub.docker.com [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/gcc)

I am under windows 11, so I need to conver the docker run commad to windows, either cmd or preferably powrshel

linux command to convert

```
docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp gcc:4.9 gcc -o hello hello.c
```

what I use in windows

```
docker run --rm -v /G/Docker/00100_start -w /G/Docker/00100_start/ gcc:4.9 gcc -o hello hello.c
```

I get this error message

```
gcc: error: hello.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Should I use another way?

Comment: If the command is executed on a docker process running on windows, `/G/Docker/...` should be a windows path, i.e. `G:/Docker/...`. A relative path (that is OS-agnostic) would also be possible.

Comment: ` -v /G/Docker/00100_start` [per the doc](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) what you've done here is to create an anonymous volume at `/G/Docker/00100_start`.  You might want to try something more like `-v /G/Docker/00100_start:/usr/src/myapp -w /usr/src/myapp` to mount local  /G/Docker/00100_start to dockets' /usr/src/myapp.  This is in addition to @Turing85's point about making sure the path works in windows